# Django returns only the id field instead of the entire object when queryset is used in subquery

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["code", "version"],
                name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_unique_code_version",
            )
        ]

    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    version = models.IntegerField()
    release_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

And the following query:

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Product.objects.order_by("code", "-version").distinct("code"),
    release_year__isnull=False
)
```

which reads:

> Out of the latest products, give me the ones with a release year.

I'm curious why the subquery does NOT require me to convert the latest products to `pk` values like so:

```
pk__in=Product.objects.order_by("code", "-version").distinct("code").values_list("pk", flat=True)
```

Looking at the raw SQL subquery using `qs.query`, looks like this is done for me automatically:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("core_product"."code")
"core_product"."id"  # only the id field is returned
FROM "core_product" 
ORDER BY "core_product"."code" ASC, "core_product"."version" DESC
```

Is this stated anywhere in the docs (a link to where this happens in the code would also be helpful)? I'm wondering which one of these variations is considered "best practice" or if there's another a better alternative (should I use Django's `Subquery` expression anywhere?). The former solution is less verbose but the latter solution is more explicit.

Comment: Are these models (Book and Product) created in django ? Are they linked with a foriegn key relation ?

Comment: @DushyantDeshwal disregard Book, just added the Product model and fixed the question

Comment: I think [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#queries-over-related-objects) is the closest that explains this feature.